Install with conan a shared object (.so) currently in src/business/task-manager instead of being in /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu like others .so
My project installs many packages with conan, then it compiles an application.
This application has one sub-project business/task-manager that creates a libtask-manager.so
So that, when I look at the executable with ldd I see that most of its shared objects are those installed by conan, but a single one comes from a sub directory of a source directory.
 ldd ./CPPTemplate 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffefafda000)
        libtask-manager.so => /workspaces/template-cpp/build/Debug/src/business/task-manager/libtask-manager.so (0x00007f2f43ca5000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2f43a83000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2f439a4000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2f43984000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f437a3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f449c4000)

When I attempt to create a docker container with the same statements I build my application locally, building is possible, but not running: that .so is missing:
docker run -it docker.registry.ourcompany.io/template:main sh

# ldd CPPTemplate
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff81924000)
    libtask-manager.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7ac1694000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f7ac1683000)
    libnsl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.2 (0x00007f7ac1668000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7ac1589000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7ac155c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7ac1379000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7ac190c000)
    libtirpc.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtirpc.so.3 (0x00007f7ac134b000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f7ac12f9000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f7ac121f000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f7ac11f2000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f7ac11ea000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f7ac11dc000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f7ac11d5000)

The libtask-manager.so => not found prevents the executable to run, and I need to make it running.
It seems to me that I have to install the
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/Debug/src/business/task-manager/libtask-manager.so
that is produced at compilation time, in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtask-manager.so
But with what conan command may I provoke that?

Here the Dockerfile that causes the "cut":
FROM gcc:bookworm AS build_base
WORKDIR /tmp/cpp-app

COPY . .

RUN  apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev

RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip install conan --break-system-packages

RUN apt remove cmake -y
RUN pip install cmake --upgrade --break-system-packages

# Release => profile: conan_release, preset: conan-release

RUN conan profile detect --force
RUN conan profile detect --name conan_release
RUN conan install . -b=missing -s compiler.cppstd=gnu17 --settings=build_type=Release --profile:build=conan_release
RUN cmake -S . --toolchain=./build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --preset conan-release
RUN cmake --build . --preset conan-release

# Unit tests
RUN ctest --test-dir ./build

# Start fresh from a smaller image
FROM gcc:bookworm

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build_base /tmp/cpp-app/CPPTemplate ./
CMD ["./CPPTemplate"]

It's the # Start fresh from a smaller image section that wipes the /src/... folder where the missing .so is hidden.
It left an image made of a single ./CPPTemplate with the missing .so
If I remove this section, I have a ./CPPTemplate that starts,
ldd ./CPPTemplate
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff417ec000)
    libtask-manager.so => /tmp/cpp-app/build/Release/src/business/task-manager/libtask-manager.so (0x00007f8afd4e6000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8afd270000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8afd25f000)
    libnsl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.2 (0x00007f8afd244000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8afd165000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8afd138000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8afcf55000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8afd5c8000)
    libtirpc.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtirpc.so.3 (0x00007f8afcf27000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f8afced5000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f8afcdfb000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f8afcdce000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f8afcdc6000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f8afcdb8000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f8afcdb1000)

but an image that is somewhat dirty:
docker run -it docker.registry.ourcompany/template:main sh                                                                               
# ls -l
total 9228
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root     814 Jun 27 03:25 CMakeLists.txt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root     140 Jun 27 07:48 CMakeUserPresets.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9385112 Jun 27 07:48 CPPTemplate
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root     146 May 28 12:18 Dockerfile
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    2862 Jun 27 07:33 Dockerfile.dev
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root     860 Jun 26 07:06 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Jun 27 07:48 build
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root     408 Jun 26 06:33 buildDocker.sh
drwxrwx--- 6 root root    4096 Jun 26 07:10 cmake-build-debug
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root     258 Jun 26 06:26 conanfile.txt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root   11812 Jun 26 07:19 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwx--- 7 root root    4096 Jun 27 03:25 src
drwxrwx--- 2 root root    4096 May 30 12:47 testFolder
drwxrwx--- 3 root root    4096 Jun  4 10:59 tests

My idea was to act after the
cmake --build . --preset conan-release

to install the libtask-manager.so with others .so, in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu where they are stored, but I don't know how to do that.

This has nothing to do with conan but with CMake and  how you package your application as a container image. Edit your question with that information instead.

@Botje Your right. It's the image builder that removes what is in /src directories (and few others directories) to gain space. This is why, before providing my compiled content to the container image creation procedure, I have to ensure that I've put a copy of my src/.../libtask-manager.so  to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

but what is the "container image creation procedure" in your case? We cannot answer without knowing THAT bit.

@Botje It's not my question. I only need the conan command that install an .so being at a place to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Once again: conan has nothing to do with this. Its job stops at making dependencies available. It has no knowledge of things beyond that. It does not even know about your application. Does your " container image creation procedure" involve running cmake --install or make install ? If so you want to add install instructions for your libtask-manager.so. If not you need to explain the procedure and its configuration.

In case it wasn't clear, by "install instructions" I mean the CMake install() command.

The executable produced by CMake in the build directory is intended to be used only on the machine where it is produced. You should NOT copy that executable to other machine and expect it to work. As you told by Botje, you need to install your project for obtain "relocatable" executable. It is your project (not a Conan) who is responsible to install all libraries needed for executable.

I've added my Dockerfile, and an experience when removing the statements that filter the image content.

@Tsyvarev was spot on. You are packaging your build tree. You should use cmake --install to install your application and its dependencies to a fresh directory (eg /target) and import /target as /usr/local in your second stage.

@Botje Just to know: this means preparing an installation configuration file, isn't it? (I've never did that before)

It could be as easy as adding install(TARGETS task-manager CPPTemplate) to your CMakeLists.txt and running cmake --install . --prefix /target --verbose. You may need to copy the snippet from the conan documentation for any shared libraries and runtime dependencies.
